# Tapping on the UIPageControl under "About this app" does not change the page, but moves the dot

Tags: bug, ios-app, tour

Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to the "About this app" screen from the menu.
2. Tap "Tricks & Tips" item.
3. Tap the page control.

Expected behavior:

Nothing, or navigate to the page tapped.

Actual behavior:

The dot of the page control moves, but the view does not scroll to the selected item.

> [image: Bug]

- App Version: 1.6.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)